# How to align cards in html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have a container which contain some cards, I want each card to start at left border of container and end at right border , like the below code.

```html
<html>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
   .card{
 border:1px solid black;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>I'm a card</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

but last 2 elements have too much space between them, how can I remove it??

I have tried adding `margin-left/right` to behave like I want but the corner cards don't touch the border. any help??

Edit: here is what i expect and[image: expected Result]

and what I get [image: what i'am getting]

Comment: Do you mean the space when viewed at smaller screens?

Comment: @Dark_thunder I have tried your code in editior [http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav1330/q32oLat1/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav1330/q32oLat1/2/) have a look. To verify I have added border to each card. It is working fine with above uploaded code.

Comment: This looks fine to me. If you have issues with spacing, perhaps let us know what screen resolution you are using that produces the problem.

Comment: wait sorry guys, I din't add `flex-wrap:wrap` , please check the issue now

Comment: @Dark_thunder As badministrator said specify your screen size where you are having problem. You can check updated url [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav1330/q32oLat1/5/)

Comment: What is your desired result? Do you want the elements on the last row to be wider or align differently? Please give an example.

Comment: ok, so I added a picture to help recreate my problem

Comment: Provide all the relevant css styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the behavior of `justify-content: space-between`. Learn about the behavior of `justify-content` visit [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)

To achieve what you wanted you can set the `container` as `block element` and set the children to be floated like `float:left`.

To avoid the unwanted spaces I removed the `margin-left` of the `.card:first-child` and `margin-right` of the `.card:last-child`

> You can specifically set the number of `card` content per a row by
>   setting a common width and clearing the `margin` space for
>   `nth-child`.Currently I made this code for 5 elements per row

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  /*setting width for each and every card element as well as -10px for removing the margin width for 5 elements*/
  width: calc( 100% / 5 - 10px);
}


/*first element*/

.container .card:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/*last element of the first row*/

.container .card:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/*first-element of the 2nd row*/

.container .card:nth-child(5n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}


/*last element*/

.container .card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>I'm a card</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first and sixth card are not aligned, that is why I did not use margin.

Comment: Let me know how many elements that you want in a row @Dark_thunder

Comment: @Dark_thunder Look at the edited answer. I considered as 6 elements per row and I have clear comments on css.

Comment: number of elements are unknown for the moment , but now if I add the 8th element ,it should be below the 2nd one and the 6th one should be touching the border of it's parent element as well.

Comment: @Dark_thunder This is mystery, you may not able to tell the total number of elements, but you must be able to tell the number of element to be placed in a row. Now check the answer. Still I have considered that there are 6 elements in a row.

Comment: well by default take it 5

Comment: @Dark_thunder check the update, now it's 5

Comment: is it possible to avoid doing selectors?? btw thanks it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I re-created your problem, but here is a codepen https://codepen.io/salallegra/pen/mQbBea that might help.

```
<html>
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: red;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .card {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: red;

    }

    body {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>I'm a card</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I removed the left and right margin of the body and placed borders around all the cards, and the container itself.

I also checked different view port sizes in Chrome developer tools and the spacing looks fine at different sizes.